# C++ Passing by Reference with Method that Returns List

Tags: c++

If i have this method below how can i return list just by reference.

```
vector<int> SudukoCell::getListData()
{
    return list;
}
```

Comment: `vector<int> &SudukoCell::getListData()`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `&` which is the reference operator. So, your function should go as follows:

```
vector<int>& SudukoCell::getListData()
{
    return list;
}
```

P.S. Although I don't know what `list` is, it's not  good practice to return a reference of one of your private lists because any change outside your instance will affect this list and your object state as a whole.

Comment: i get an error if i do that it just says its incompatible.

Comment: What is `list`? Isn't it a `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @churill yeah that is what list is and its private.

Comment: Then please clarify this in your question. Add the exact error message and show some more code, a [mre] at best.